# Randomly shuffle rows in a large text file

Tags: macos, awk, text-editing

I have a text file of ~1GB with about 6k rows (each row is very long) and I need to randomly shuffle its rows. Is it possible? Possibly with awk?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`shuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html) command from **GNU coreutils**. The utility is pretty fast and would take less than a minute for shuffling a 1 GB file.

The command below might just work in your case because `shuf` will read the complete input before opening the output file:

```
$ shuf -o File.txt < File.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I am on OSX, any equivalents?

Comment: @ddmichael Run `brew install coreutils` and use `/usr/local/bin/gshuf`.

Comment: @ddmichael Alternatively for OS X you can use this Perl one liner. Got this one one of the old blogs. Did a quick test and found working.

`cat myfile | perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print shuffle(<STDIN>);'`

_I am note sure how fast would it run though_

Answer (score 4):

Python 3 one-liner:

```sh
python3 -c "import sys, random; L = sys.stdin.readlines(); random.shuffle(L); print(''.join(L), end='')"
```

Python 2 one-liner:

```sh
python2 -c "import sys, random; L = sys.stdin.readlines(); random.shuffle(L); print ''.join(L),"
```

Reads all the lines from the standard input, shuffles them in-place, then prints them without adding an ending newline (notice the `end=''` or `,` from the end).

Answer (score 1):

If like me you came here to look for an alternate to `shuf` for macOS then use `randomize-lines`.

Install `randomize-lines`(homebrew) package, which has an `rl` command which has similar functionality to `shuf`.

`brew install randomize-lines`

```
Usage: rl [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Randomize the lines of a file (or stdin).

  -c, --count=N  select N lines from the file
  -r, --reselect lines may be selected multiple times
  -o, --output=FILE
                 send output to file
  -d, --delimiter=DELIM
                 specify line delimiter (one character)
  -0, --null     set line delimiter to null character
                 (useful with find -print0)
  -n, --line-number
                 print line number with output lines
  -q, --quiet, --silent
                 do not output any errors or warnings
  -h, --help     display this help and exit
  -V, --version  output version information and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

For OSX the binary is called `gshuf`.

```
brew install coreutils
gshuf -o File.txt < File.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot where I found this, but here's the `shuffle.pl` that I use:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# @(#) randomize Effectively _unsort_ a text file into random order.
# 96.02.26 / drl.
# Based on Programming Perl, p 245, "Selecting random element ..."

# Set the random seed, PP, p 188
srand(time|$$);

# Suck in everything in the file.
@a = <>;

# Get random lines, write 'em out, mark 'em done.
while ( @a ) {
        $choice = splice(@a, rand @a, 1);
        print $choice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in ubuntu, there's a program called `shuf`

```
shuf file.txt
```

Comment: That program is part of coreutils, as mentioned by [Suraj Biyani](http://superuser.com/a/760754/2357).